Angular Deferable Views tests just won't work
So I've been messing around with adding Deferable Views to my Angular app. However, doing so breaks the unit tests for everything that's behind a @defer. What happens is that no code works if it's behind the defer. For example, take the following code:
          <div class="foo">{{ "a" }}</div>
            @defer (on immediate) {
              <div class="bar">{{ "b" }}</div>

And the following in the tests:
    console.log(0);
    console.log(fixture.debugElement.query(By.css(".foo")));
    console.log(1);
    console.log(fixture.debugElement.query(By.css(".bar")));

And the console output is this:
0
DebugElement{nativeNode: <div _ngcontent-a-c173546202="" class="foo">a</div>}
1
DebugElement{nativeNode: <div _ngcontent-a-c173546202="" class="bar"></div>}

So what in the world is going on? How is the string "b" null? Note that this is using Playthrough mode. When I try Manual mode, getDeferBlocks returns empty list.
I'd love to share the entire code, but it's bloated with a 160 line template, 300 lines of component, and 1000 lines of test. Of course, that's a big part of the problem, but I can't do much about it at this time. :(

@defer only works for standalone components. div is not a standalone component.

@MatthieuRiegler Yes, I know. I'm not actually trying to defer the div. That wouldn't do anything. It's just how I was testing the fact that it does the same thing with components. When it's a standalone component, it shows it as receiving no inputs.

Maybe it's an async or a refresh issue? Have you tried to tick and/or detect changes? Or are you using jest (it has often weird behavior because it's using jsdom and not a real browser)?
